# WinSCP: SFTP script to transfer then move local files to another folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, sftp, winscp

I got my SFTP script with WinSCP to work, but the last part that moves the files in the `ready` folder to the `sent` folder won't work.

```
move "C:\SFTP stuff\ready\*.*" "C:\SFTP stuff\sent"
```

`Deploy.txt` (file name):

```
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP" 
Winscp.com /script="C:\SFTP stuff\FTPwinscp.txt"
```

`FTPwinscp.txt`:

```
open sftp://FTP ADDRESS:8022/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa REALLY LONG KEY="
put "C:\SFTP stuff\ready\*.*" "/incoming/x12/"
cd "C:\SFTP stuff\"
move "C:\SFTP stuff\ready\*.*" "C:\SFTP stuff\sent"
```

After `put` command, I expected the script to continue down and transfer the files to the other folder.  After script runs, it only transfers.  I tried the `move` script as its own txt file, and it moves the files as expected.  Am I implementing this incorrectly? Fist time tackling this.

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP does not have `move` command. WinSCP does not have any command to move local files to another local folder.

There's [Windows `move` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move), with the syntax you are using. So you need to move the `move` command from WinSCP script into your batch file. And you should call `move`, only when WinSCP succeeds.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP" 
winscp.com /script="C:\SFTP stuff\FTPwinscp.txt"

if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
    move "C:\SFTP stuff\ready\*.*" "C:\SFTP stuff\sent"
)
```

---

All this is covered in WinSCP article [Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload).
*(The first hit in Google for your question title)*

Comment: Thank you, i got it working now, I am still now sure what, 

"if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error
 
echo Upload succeeded, moving local files"

Does but I will read up on it more.  This gave me better insight for next time!